# Algoritmo de Monte Carlo para árboles binarios

Tags: python, python-3.x, búsqueda-monte-carlo

Intenté aplicar el algoritmo de Monte Carlo a árboles binarios, pero tengo la impresión de que hay un error en el algoritmo porque devuelve mi valor predeterminado.

Aqui esta la estructura del arbol de una manera grafica :

```
               10
             /    \
            6      14
           / \    /  \
          5   8  11  18
```

Pueden obtenerlo [sobre GitHub](https://github.com/antoinecomp/NestedMonteCarloForBinaryTrees/blob/master/main.py) pero aqui esta el algoritmo :

```
# Attempt to apply a Nested Monte Carlo Algorithm to binary trees

from random import *
import numpy as np

MaxPlayoutLength = 20 # what ?

# Class for construct the nodes of the tree. (Subtrees)
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, parent_node = None):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.key = key
        if parent_node == None:
            self.parent = self
        else:
            self.parent = parent_node

# Class with the  structure of the tree. 
# I'm not sure if this Tree is balanced.
class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    # Insert a single element
    def insert(self, x):
        if(self.root == None):
            self.root = Node(x)
        else:
            self._insert(x, self.root)

    # place it at the right palce
    def _insert(self, x, node):
        if(x < node.key):
            if(node.left == None):
                node.left = Node(x, node)
            else:
                self._insert(x, node.left)
        else:
            if(node.right == None):
                node.right = Node(x, node)
            else:
                self._insert(x, node.right)

    # Given a element, return a node in the tree with key x. 
    def find(self, x):
        if(self.root == None):
            return None
        else:
            return self._find(x, self.root)

    def _find(self, x, node):
        if(x == node.key):
            return node
        elif(x < node.key):
            if(node.left == None):
                return None
            else:
                return self._find(x, node.left)
        elif(x > node.key):
            if(node.right == None):
                return None
            else:
                return self._find(x, node.right)

    # Given a node, return the node in the tree with the next largest element.
    def next(self, node):
        if node.right != None:
            return self._left_descendant(node.right)
        else:
            return self._right_ancestor(node)

    def _left_descendant(self, node):
        if node.left == None:
            return node
        else:
            return self._left_descendant(node.left)

    def _right_ancestor(self, node):
        if node.key <= node.parent.key:
            return node.parent
        else:
            return self._right_ancestor(node.parent)

    # Delete an element of the tree
    def delete(self, x):
        node = self.find(x)
        if node == None:
            print(x, "isn't in the tree")
        else:
            if node.right == None:
                if node.left == None:
                    if node.key < node.parent.key:
                        node.parent.left = None
                        del node # Clean garbage
                    else:
                        node.parent.right = None
                        del Node # Clean garbage
                else:
                    node.key = node.left.key
                    node.left = None
            else:
                x = self.next(node)
                node.key = x.key
                x = None

# a tree with a selected node at a given time
class Board:
    '''a Board is a tree with a node selected which gives a score'''
    def __init__(self, btree):
        self.tree = btree
        self.root = btree.root
        self.root.left = btree.root.left
        self.root.right = btree.root.right

        print("Board initialized")
        print("root :")
        print(self.root.key)
        print("btree.root.left")
        print(btree.root.left)
        print("btree.root.right")
        print(btree.root.right)

        # length = NULL; //TO-DO : number of nodes which have leaves BUT how to count them ?

        moves = np.zeros(2) 
        if(btree.root.left != None):
            self.moves[0] = btree.root.left #/DONE? 
            self.moves[1] = btree.root.right
            score = btree.root.key

    def legalMoves(self, moves):
        if(moves.all != None):
            return 2
        elif(moves.any != None):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    def terminal(self):
        if((self.root.left == None) and (self.root.right  == None)):
            print("board terminal")
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def score(self):
        return node.key

    def getLegalMoves(self,node):
        if(node.left != None):
            self.moves[0] = node.left
            self.moves[1] = node.right
            return moves

    def play(self,key):
        '''chose the next node we dive into, if legal :
        - node : next node the player wants to dive into
        '''
        # no test for the moment, let's see if it can make it
        node = self.tree.find(key)
        self.root = node
        self.root.left = node.left
        self.root.right = node.right

        # length = NULL; //TO-DO : number of nodes which have leaves BUT how to count them ?

def playout(board):
    moves[2]# shoudln't we get them from the board ?
    while(True):
        nb = board.legalMoves(self.moves)
        if((nb == 0) or board.terminal()):
            return board.score()
        n = random.randint(0, nb) # chose a number between 0 and the number of legal moves
        board.play(moves[n]) # play a random move
        if(board.length >= MaxPlayoutLength -20):
            return 0

bestScoreNested = -9999
DBL_MAX = -9999

arraySize = 10

lengthBestRollout = np.zeros(10) # array of size 10
scoreBestRollout = np.zeros(10) # array of size 10

bestRollout =np.zeros((10,MaxPlayoutLength)) # 2 dimensional array of size 10*MaxPlayoutLength

def nested(board, n):
    '''Nested Monte Carlo algorithm
    a general name for a broad class of algorithms that use random sampling to obtain numerical results.
    It is used to solve statistical problems by simulation.'''

    nbMoves = 0
    moves = np.zeros(2)

    lengthBestRollout[n] -1
    scoreBestRollout[n] - DBL_MAX
    res = -DBL_MAX
    while(True):
        # if it's over we've reached the bottom of the tree
        if(board.terminal()):
            return 0.0
        nbMoves = board.legalMoves(moves) # moves is full of 0s here ... what has bestRollout[n][board.length] then ?
        for i in range(0,nbMoves):
            b = board
            b.play(moves[i])
            if(n==1):
                playout(board)
            else:
                nested (board, n-1)
                score = board.score()
            if(score > scoreBestRollout [n]):
                scoreBestRollout [n] = score
                lengthBestRollout [n] = board.length
                for k in range(0,board.length):
                    bestRollout[n][k]=board.rollout[k]
                if(n>3):
                    for i in range(0,t<n-1):
                        print("n =", n,"progress =", board.length, "score =", scoreBestRollout [n])
                        depth = 0
                        # board.print(stderr) # what 
                        print("")
                        bestBoard = board
                if ((n > 1) and (score > bestScoreNested)):
                    bestScoreNested = score
                    print("best score = ", score)
                    print("")
                    bestBoard = board
        board.play(bestRollout[n][board.length])
    return 0.0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # tests
    t = Tree()
    t.insert(5)
    t.insert(6)
    t.insert(8)
    t.insert(10)
    t.insert(11)
    t.insert(14)
    t.insert(18)

    b = Board(t)

    score = nested(b,3)
    print("the algorithm score is ",score)

    # Remember: Find method return the node object. 
    # To return a number use t.find(nº).key
    # But it will cause an error if the number is not in the tree.
```

El problemo esta que al compilar el codigo obtengo :

```
$ python3 main.py 
board terminal
None
the algorithm score is  0.0
```

Parece que el no empeza correctamente con el primer nodo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo el código está claro lo que pasa: se invoca la función `nested` con un nodo cuya rama izquierda está vacía, por lo que se corta la exploración del árbol en el método `terminal`. Aparte de esto, <strike>no entiendo bien cómo quieres aplicar un método Montecarlo sin aleatoriedad</strike> no veo de qué módulo importas la función `rand()`.

Comment: `from random import *` Había olvidadola :p Voy a ver con más detalle este nudo que no debería ser sin niños